# Error "Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity" when taken from CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to disable a PCs from a CSV file , however i keep getting the below error .

The code works when I manually copy the list of Devices into a text file (notepad)

Thanks

> Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'PC-125632 '
>   under: 'DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX'. At line:12 char:15 + $ADComputer =
>   Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties Description+
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**Here is what i have tried so far**

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\test.csv |  Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content C:\Temp\List.txt
$Computers = Get-Content C:\Temp\List.txt
Start-Sleep -s 5    
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)    
{     
    $ADComputer = $null    
    $ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties Description    
    If ($ADComputer)    
    { 
        Add-Content c:\temp\computers.log -Value "The following PC $Computer has been found and disabled"    
        Set-ADComputer $ADComputer -Description "$($ADComputer.Description)- Disable due to inactivity - $(Get-Date) - by $env:UserName " -Enabled $False    
    }    
    Else    
    { 
    Add-Content c:\temp\computers.log -Value "$Computer not Found in Active Directory or Was disabled before"    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Use `import-csv` to read an csv file and not `get-content `

Comment: What does your csv file look like? Is there a computer in your environment named PC-125632?

Comment: @guiwhatsthat  I used import-csv but its still giving me the same error .@EBGreen The file is small , it has one header ( DeviceName which i removed ) and 20 devices and Yes we do have that name

Comment: No need to remove the header, use Import-Csv and then define the property you want to use with foreach: `$Computers = Import-Csv C:\temp\test.csv` and `Foreach ($Computer in $Computers.DeviceName)`

Comment: @Dandano See the final edit of the answer, you can adopt/edit if needed. on the whole it works without errors and disables the pcs using a csv

Comment: @James : Yea that took care of the header but im still getting the same error above (Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'PC-125632 ' under: ) . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message does show the issue, but it is quite subtle... there is a trailing space (at the end the computer name):

> 'PC-125632 '

This is being taken as part of the computer name, when it should not be included.

It's easy to fix by using [`Trim()`](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/07/18/trim-your-strings-with-powershell/) to remove any leading or trailing whitespace.

I'm also using `Import-Csv` as per my earlier comment, and `-Filter "Name -eq $Computer"` as this will return null is there are no matches.

```
$Computers = Import-Csv C:\temp\test.csv

Foreach ($Computer in $Computers.DeviceName) {
    $Computer = $Computer.Trim()
    $ADComputer = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq $Computer" -Properties Description
    If ($ADComputer) {
        Add-Content c:\temp\computers.log -Value "The following PC $Computer has been found and disabled"
        Set-ADComputer $ADComputer -Description "$($ADComputer.Description)- Disable due to inactivity - $(Get-Date) - by $env:UserName " -Enabled $False
    }
    Else {
        Add-Content c:\temp\computers.log -Value "$Computer not Found in Active Directory or Was disabled before"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info . The trim() worked , i did not use the Filter as it was giving some weird error . Here is what i used                                                                                                            $Computer = $Computer.Trim()

    $ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties Description

Answer (score 0):

> Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'PC-125632 '
>   under: 'DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XXX'. At line:12 char:15 + $ADComputer =
>   Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties Description+

Above error is rectified by (2) and (3)

Below code I have executed successfully. It works fine ..

(1)I have change the way the csv is imported.

```
 $computers=Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\test.csv"
```

(2)and instead of

```
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers)
```

I use

```
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers.distinguishedName)
```

rest are same ..

On the whole it looks like this,

```
$computers=Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\test.csv" 

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers.distinguishedName)    
{     
    $ADComputer = $null    
    $ADComputer = Get-ADComputer $Computer -Properties Description    
    If ($ADComputer)    
    { 
        Add-Content c:\temp\computers.log -Value "The following PC $Computer has been found and disabled"    
        Set-ADComputer $ADComputer -Description "$($ADComputer.Description)- Disable due to inactivity - $(Get-Date) - by $env:UserName " -Enabled $False    
    }    
    Else    
    { 
    Add-Content c:\temp\computers.log -Value "$Computer not Found in Active Directory or Was disabled before"    
    }    
}
```

(3) Where my csv format is like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info but Unfortunately that did not work as im still getting the ( (Get-ADComputer : Cannot find an object with identity: 'PC-125632 ' under)

Comment: have u used my code as it is with csv format shown?

Comment: @Aravinda - it works for you as you are not using the same source data. The issue is actually with the computer name having a trailing space, the error does show this but it's quite subtle and easily missed. Your code changes do not rectify this so OP still gets the same error.